# Hide label when select item from list - javascript

Tags: javascript

How i can hide label when the user select item from list , i have this code to hide input text , but how i can hide the label for that input text?

```
<form name="myform">
<table>
<td>
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex==8){this.myform['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.myform['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<label>Other</label><input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

i want to hide `<label>Other</label>`  how i can do that ?

Comment: `selectedIndex` is a number, not a string.

Comment: Did you mean to check the `.value` property instead?

Comment: @lan not the value of input text , the label <label>Other</label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7NL9A/)

you can not match text or value of dropdown  like this `this.selectedIndex`

change it to `this.selectedIndex == 8` to match the index

give textbox `id="other"` to show or hide it.

```
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex== 8){document.getElementById('other').style.visibility='visible'}else {document.getElementById('other').style.visibility='hidden'};">
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7NL9A/1/)

made new id for label `l_other`

```
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex== 8){document.getElementById('l_other').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('other').style.visibility='visible'}else {document.getElementById('l_other').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('other').style.visibility='hidden'};">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7NL9A/2/)

Making use of single div with id `other` wrap `label` and `textbox` inside it

```
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex== 8){
document.getElementById('other').style.visibility='visible'}else{
document.getElementById('other').style.visibility='hidden'}">
```

Comment: @AbdullahAl-hazmy you can cover your label and input with some div and make that div visible/hidden on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select tag and input text as below.

```
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex=='other'){document.getElementById("otherText").style.visibility='visible'}else {document.getElementById("otherText").style.visibility='hidden'};">


<div id="otherText" style="visibility:hidden;"><label>Other</label><input type="textbox" name="other" /></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnChange(that) {            
        var lblOther = document.getElementById('lblOther');
        if (that.options[that.selectedIndex].text == 'Other') {                
            lblOther.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {               
            lblOther.style.display = "none";               
        };
    }

<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <td>
            <select name="one" onchange="OnChange(this);">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <label id="lblOther" style="display: block;">Other</label><input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility: hidden;" />
        </td>
    </table>
</form>
```